# Remove Filter for a Visual in PowerBI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI report Embedded with some visuals. If we apply visual filter it is filtering all Visuals. What I want is if I select any particular Visual the filter applied for the Visual should be removed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataSelected` event to select a particular visual. To remove filters from the selected visual, use `updateFilters`. Here is the code:

```
// report.on will add an event listener.
report.on("dataSelected", function (event) {
    const pages = await report.getPages();

    // Retrieve the active page.
    let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
        return page.isActive
    })[0];

    const visuals = await page.getVisuals();

    // Select the Visual
    let data = event.detail;

    // Retrieve the target visual.
    let visual = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
        return visual.name === data.visual.name;
    })[0];

        // Remove the ​filters applied to the visual
       await visual.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.RemoveAll);
    });
```

References:

[Data Selected Event Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events#dataselected)

[Control Report Filter - Power BI Embedded](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters#filters-operation)